# Remove first N lines from an active log file without logrotate

Tags: linux, embedded-linux

Is there a way to remove the first N lines from a log that is being actively appended by an application without using logrotate? (opkg install logrotate -returns: Unknow package 'logrotate')

Answer (score -1):

The best answer install logrotate.
Next

tail -n +10 /var/log/whatever.log

replace the +10 with any number, but be sure to keep the + symbol.

Answer (score -1):

Sed is the easiest solution to manipulate text files:

```
sed -i '1,Nd' /path_to_log
```